# Assembly 32bit - compare char

Tags: c, assembly

I have a C program that calls a function written in 32bit assembly which check if the input is a character or a number, then return 1 else return 0.
I've done something wrong because the comparison return to me always the same result.

Here the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int aisalnum(int *ascii);

//char atoupper(char *a);
//char astripnoalnum(char str[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char input;
  int a;
  printf("\nPremi un tasto: ");
  scanf("%c",&input);

  a = (int)(input);

  int result = aisalnum(&a);
//  printf("\nAssembly ritorna: %d",result);
  if(result == 1)
    {
      printf("\nIl carattere e' una lettera o un numero\n");
    }else{
      printf("\n\nIl carattere non e' ne lettera ne numero\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

And here the assembly function:

```
extern printf

global aisalnum
global atoupper
global astripnoalnum

;----------------------------------------------; 
;La funzione riceve un parametro;
;verifica se è una lettera o un numero;
;e ritorna 1, altrimenti ritorna 0;
;----------------------------------------------;

aisalnum:
    PUSH    EBP     ;salvo ebp
    MOV EBP,ESP     ;carico lo stack pointer nel base pointer

    XOR EBX,EBX     ;azzero il registro nel quale poi
    MOV EBX,[EBP+8] ;recupero il parametro inserito
    PUSH    EBX
    CALL    printf
    POP EAX

    CMP EBX,48      ;verifico se il carattere ottenuto è maggiore di 48(zero)
    JAE up_o        ;e salto a up_o (up of zero);
    JMP none        ;se è minore non è ne lettera ne numero

up_o:   CMP EBX,57      ;verifico che il carattere sia minore o uguale di 57(nove)
    JBE num     ;e salto a num (il carattere è un numero)
    JMP     ver_c       ;altrimenti verifico se è una lettera

ver_c:  CMP EBX,65      ;verifico se il carattere è maggiore o uguale di 65(A)
    JAE up_A        ;e salto ad up_A (up of 'A')
    JMP     none        ;altrimenti non è nemmeno una lettera e salto

up_A:   CMP EBX,90      ;verifico se il carattere è minore o uguale di 90(Z)
    JBE char        ;e salto a char (il carattere è una lettera)
    JMP min     ;altrimenti potrebbe essere una lettera minuscola

min:    CMP EBX,97      ;verifico se è maggiore ouguale di 97(a)
    JAE up_a        ;e salto ad up_a (up of 'a')

up_a:   CMP EBX,122     ;verifico se è minore o uguale a 122(z)
    JBE char        ;e salto a char (il carattere è una lettera)
    JMP none        ;altrimenti non è un carattere e salto a none

none:   MOV EAX,2       ;il carattere non è ne lettera ne numero
    LEAVE
    RET         ;carico 0 in EAX e termino

char:   MOV EAX,1       ;il carattere è una lettera qundi termino
    LEAVE
    RET

num:    MOV EAX,1       ;il carattere è un numero quindi termino
    LEAVE
    RET
```

I've even tried to use the ASCII's hex value of the char and the char itself but always the function jump to 'none' and returns 0.

What I get wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling your function with the *address of* `a` as the argument. So when you do `MOV EBX,[EBP+8]` you're getting that address, not the value stored at that address.

Before the first `CMP` you should add an `MOV EBX, [EBX]` to get the value of `a` (just don't add it before the call to `printf`, because that would cause the `printf` to fail).